# Large .xsession-errors file, PulseAudio

Tags: disk-space, kde, ubuntu-16.04, pulse-audio

On Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS), x64, I am facing the following problem: .xsession-errors, in home folder is growing very fast, reaching sizes of tens of GB.

I just forcibly truncated the file (echo "" > .xsession-errors ), as a temporary fix, then copied the file that started growing again, to a different location, to inspect what is going on.

Looks like the file is filled with the following lines, repeated over and over again.

`org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: Attempting connection to PulseAudio sound daemon
org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: state callback
org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: state callback`

Any hints on how I could fix this? I am not using / don't need sound on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your KDE is configured to use Pulse Audio as an engine for Phonon Backend, and for some reason the Pulse Audio daemon itself is not installed/not responding.

I suggest you make sure the `phonon-backend-gstreamer` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install phonon-backend-gstreamer
```

and then go to KDE audio preferences and check that "Gstreamer" is configured as a backend.

Completely uninstall pulseaudio and make `gstreamer` use `alsa` instead:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install alsa-base alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsa-oss linux-sound-base alsamixergui

sudo apt-get install esound esound-clients esound-common libesd-alsa0 gnome-alsamixer
```

Then restart your computer.

After that, run

```
gstreamer-properties
```

to setup Gstreamer defaults (which now will use `alsa`).

Then check if the errors related to Pulse Audio go away.

Answer (score 2):

One option, edit the file `/etc/X11/Xsession`, for example:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession
```

Then modifty the `ERRFILE` variable so errors are sent to `/dev/null`.

```
## ERRFILE=$HOME/.xsession-errors
ERRFILE=/dev/null
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Super User! While this may fix the `.xsession-errors` file growing out of control, I think the real problem the OP is asking about is the continuous output of PulseAudio errors.

Comment: Re: Welcome from Mr Shunz!  comments ....

While this may fix the .xsession-errors file growing out of control, I think the real problem the OP is asking about is the continuous output of PulseAudio errors. 

That is why I said "One option" and didn't say preferred option etc.  I did find other "solutions" eventually, perhaps you could have posted one of those instead of an irrelevant comment on the fact that there might be better solutions? In the file I mention you can also alter the max file size for instance ....